# Сортировка данных по дате(дню месяца)?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица `action`

```
 id  date
 1 | 2019-02-01
 2 | 2019-02-02    
 3 | 2019-02-02    
 4 | 2019-02-02    
 5 | 2019-02-13    
 6 | 2019-02-13
```

**MySQL запрос**

```
SELECT COUNT(id) as `count`
     , DAYOFMONTH(date) as `date` 
FROM action 
WHERE MONTH(`date`) = MONTH(NOW()) 
      AND YEAR(`date`) = YEAR(NOW()) 
GROUP BY DAYOFMONTH(date)
```

**Результат**

```
Array (
    [count] => 1
    [date] => 1
)    
Array (
    [count] => 3
    [date] => 2
)    
Array (
    [count] => 1
    [date] => 13
)
```

Сейчас получил количество действий(записей) за каждый день нынешнего месяца.

**Вопрос**
Как получить 0 за дни, в которых не было записи?

По итогу хочу вывести на страницу такие данные

```
1 число | Действий 1
2 число | Действий 3    
3 число | Действий 0    
4 число | Действий 0    
...    
13 число | Действий 1    
...
```

До последнего числа месяца.

Прошу помощи! Ответа за весь день не нашел, видать плохо ищу.

Comment: Вы знаете месяц по которому ищете данные. Возьмите количество дней в нем и шагайте циклом. Если текущий день есть в массиве - выводите.

Comment: вам нужно решить это с помощью MySql или же можно с помощью PHP?

Comment: На PHP. В данный момент получил результат следующим образом.
Создал массив с датами от 1 до 31. Прибавил его к результату из БД. 
Желаемое получил, но вышло колхозно. Пока ищу способ "мудрого" решения вопроса.

Comment: колхозно не всегда плохо. но ...